# Shift elements in string array until chosen letter is at index 0

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings like `first_page = {{"U","M","Y","Q","I","A","L","D","P","F","E","G","T","Z","V","W","H","O","X","J","C","R","B","S","N","K"}`

Now if I type in `A`, it searches for the `A` (there will be only one `A` in the string) and keeps shifting the `A` and every element by one index up, element under the last index gets shifted to index `0`, while the `A` is not at index `0`.

What is the easiest way to achieve it? I am having troubles, and my current not so working code is the following:

```
   for(int i = 0; i<25;i++) {
        help[i] = first_page[keys_int[0]][i];
                  } 
    for(int i = 0; i<25;i++) {

       if(first_page[keys_int[0]][i].equals(plain_chars[0].toUpperCase())) {
           rememberedi = i;
          int k = i;

            do {

                first_page_copy[keys_int[0]][k+1] = help[k];
                first_page_copy[keys_int[0]][k] = help[k-1];

                k++;
                if(k==24) {
                    first_page_copy[keys_int[0]][k+1] = help[k];
                          first_page_copy[keys_int[0]][0] = help[24];
                          k = 1;
                }

              }while(!first_page[keys_int[0]][0].equals(plain_chars[0]));
            i = 26;
       }
    }
```

The array is multidimensional but I am working only with a row from a chosen column.

I copy the entire row in the array to the array `help`, then keep replacing the next element from where I am at with current, and current with previous.
Thanx for any responses.

Comment: Design an algo, then code it. This is a typical case of trying to program something that is not well-understood.

Comment: Could you explain what your desired result is for your example? I don't understand what you have written.

Comment: I'll also add if this is homework, please indicate as such.  There's various tricks which I'd recommend to someone who was looking to use this code in production that I can't imagine a teacher would view as understanding the material.

Comment: it is not a homework, I am testing out something. The desired result is to get the chosen letter, in my example A which is at index 5 to shift it to index 0 one step at a time to the right ( to a higher index).. shift it to index 6..then 7... when at the last index shift to 0 and loop would end, as that is what I want.  Obviously every other letter has to shift by one too, otherwise every element would end up being A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers already said the first step is to find the index of the character which should be shifted to position `0`.

```
private static int indexOf(char character, char[] characters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == character) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Then we can use the classes `Arrays` and `System` to perform the shifting in a fast way.

```
protected static void shiftRight(char character, char[] characters) {
    int indexOf = indexOf(character, characters);
    if (indexOf > 0) {
        char[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(characters, 0, indexOf);
        System.arraycopy(characters, indexOf, characters, 0, characters.length - indexOf);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, characters, characters.length - temp.length, temp.length);
    }
}
```

If `indexOf` is less than `0` the `character` was not found. If `indexOf`is `0` then `characters` need no shift as the array already has the desired state. In both cases no shift takes place.

Applying this to the characters from the question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char character = 'A';
    char[] characters = { 'U', 'M', 'Y', 'Q', 'I', 'A', 'L', 'D', 'P', 'F', 'E', 'G', 'T', 'Z', 'V', 'W', 'H', 'O', 'X', 'J', 'C', 'R', 'B', 'S', 'N', 'K' };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(characters));      
    shiftRight(character, characters);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(characters));
}
```

This prints:

```
[U, M, Y, Q, I, A, L, D, P, F, E, G, T, Z, V, W, H, O, X, J, C, R, B, S, N, K] 
[A, L, D, P, F, E, G, T, Z, V, W, H, O, X, J, C, R, B, S, N, K, U, M, Y, Q, I]
```

---

Please note:
Instead of an array of `String` which is used in the question, I'm using an array of `char` since each `String` contains only a letter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yours was the easiest to understand and implement.

Comment: Almost the same time I wrote "OP is not responsive" you've got the response. No other option for me than +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a lot of unnecessary shifting.
Just let me know if I get this right:
e.g.:
{A,B,C,D,E,F,G} - types 'E' - result: {E,F,G,A,B,C,D}

In that case: just find the index of 'E' first, then you can do a for- loop (no need for do - while)

```
for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++){
    target[i] = source[(i+index)%source.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array shifting algorithm is pretty simple. It is better to show it on example:

1. Initial array `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}`
2. You want to make `'c'` be the first element, so shift array to the left for `offs = 2` positions
3. **Step 1**: reverse all elements in the array: `{'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'}`
4. **Step 2**: reverse first `3` elements `arr.length - offs = 5 - 2 = 3`: `{'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a'}`
5. **Step 3**: reverse last `2` elements `offs = 2`: `{'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'}`
6. Here you are, you have shifted given array for 2 positions left.

You can do all this **in place**, without creating temporary array. This is good approach, especially for huge arrays.

```
public static void shiftArray(char[] arr, char ch) {
    int pos = indexOf(arr, ch);

    if (pos > 0) {
        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - pos - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
        for (int i = arr.length - pos, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}
```

Helper methods:

```
private static int indexOf(char[] arr, char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == ch)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char ch = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no need for loops in your code. Some time-expensive stuffs like copy of arrays are implemented in Java to be as fast as they could.

One of these is `System.arraycopy(`.
Knowing that, your goal is to find the index of desired `String` in the input array and copy the array in the way you needs.

The API doc for `arraycopy` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)).

This would be the fastest way I can figure to do it:

```
public class Answer {

    private static int findIndexOf(String[] array, String string) {
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
            if (array[index].equals(string))
                return index;
        return -1;
    }

    private static String[] shift(String[] input, String string) {
        String[] result = new String[input.length];
        int offset = findIndexOf(input, string);
        if (offset != -1) {
            System.arraycopy(input, offset, result, 0, input.length - offset);
            System.arraycopy(input, 0, result, input.length - offset, offset);
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //test
        String[] input =
                {"U", "M", "Y", "Q", "I", "A", "L", "D", "P", "F", "E", "G", "T", "Z", "V", "W", "H", "O", "X", "J", "C", "R", "B", "S", "N", "K"};

        String[] desiredOutput =
                {"A", "L", "D", "P", "F", "E", "G", "T", "Z", "V", "W", "H", "O", "X", "J", "C", "R", "B", "S", "N", "K", "U", "M", "Y", "Q", "I"};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(desiredOutput));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shift(input, "A")));

    }
}
```

The output of this code:

```
[A, L, D, P, F, E, G, T, Z, V, W, H, O, X, J, C, R, B, S, N, K, U, M, Y, Q, I]
[A, L, D, P, F, E, G, T, Z, V, W, H, O, X, J, C, R, B, S, N, K, U, M, Y, Q, I]
```

**Note:** If you want the result in the same array, you can do it like this:

```
input = shift(input, "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

To *only* shift an array until the first value is equal to a given string, you could do

```
private static boolean shiftToString(String[] strings, String search) {
    assert strings != null : "null strings";
    assert strings.length > 0 : "empty strings";
    assert search != null : "null search";

    int count = 0;

    while (count++ < strings.length) {
        if (strings[0].equals(search))
            return true;  // or count - 1
        String last = strings[strings.length-1];
        for (int i = strings.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
            strings[i] = strings[i-1];
        }
        strings[0] = last;
    }
    return false;
}
```

it is nothing fancy, just what was asked for - the count is used to stop if the value is not found.

<sup>actually this can be solved by just copying 2 parts of the array,I know, but just to test something out</sup>

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question and your comment I can assume that you want to shift the whole **2D Array** of Strings step by step. Of course, I also assumed that each row in this case is the same size.

Now, I decided to write the another answer which include the *entire code* (also step by step), so you can explore it and change it as you wish.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Answer {

    //testCase - 2D matrix of Strings:
    private static final String[][] testCase =
            {
                    {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"},
                    {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"},
                    {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}
            };
    private static final String testSearch = "C";


    //find the index of searchString in the array of strings
    private static int findIndexOf(String[] strings, String searchString) {

        for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index++)
            if (strings[index].equals(searchString))
                return index;  //searchString found at index
        return -1;             //searchString not found
    }

    //shifting one row by one step
    private static String[] shiftToRightByOneStep(String[] strings) {

        String[] result = strings;
        String last = strings[strings.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(strings, 0, result, 1, strings.length - 1);
        result[0] = last;
        return result;
    }

    //shifting matrix by one step
    private static String[][] shiftMatrixToRightByOneStep(String[][] matrix) {

        String[][] result = matrix;
        for (String[] row : matrix) {
            shiftToRightByOneStep(row);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] myMatrix = testCase;
        String find = testSearch;
        int howManySteps = myMatrix[0].length - findIndexOf(myMatrix[0], find);
        System.out.println("Shifting matrix by " + howManySteps + " steps");
        System.out.println("Original matrix:\n" + Arrays.deepToString(testCase) + "\n_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("STEPS:");
        for (int step = 0; step < howManySteps; step++)
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(shiftMatrixToRightByOneStep(myMatrix)) + "\n_____________________________________");

        //testing is it original matrix changed
        // (of course it is, b/c I used references instead of copies)
        System.out.println("Original matrix:\n" + Arrays.deepToString(testCase));
    }
}
```

Output:

Shifting matrix by 5 steps

Original matrix:

[[A, B, C, D, E, F, G], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]]

---

STEPS:

[[G, A, B, C, D, E, F], [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [g, a, b, c, d, e, f]]

---

[[F, G, A, B, C, D, E], [5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [f, g, a, b, c, d, e]]

---

[[E, F, G, A, B, C, D], [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3], [e, f, g, a, b, c, d]]

---

[[D, E, F, G, A, B, C], [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2], [d, e, f, g, a, b, c]]

---

[[C, D, E, F, G, A, B], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1], [c, d, e, f, g, a, b]]

---

Original matrix:

[[C, D, E, F, G, A, B], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1], [c, d, e, f, g, a, b]]

Comment: @LuCio Totally agreed, but since there is no response from OP, I left **both** of my answers assuming that she/he want solution on the plate.

Comment: I removed my comment. because though it's possible to transfer a 2D array or view a 2D as an ordinary array (concatenated rows), the result would be a different if we shift right every row with overflow on the row or if we shift right the whole matrix with overflow on its beginning.

Comment: @LuCio Of course! That's why I wrote _ I also assumed that each row in this case is the same size_. Also, I didn't check if `findIndexOf` returns `-1`. This is an answer suitable to explore the possibilities. Cheers, friend.